# How do I get a stored procedure output parameter that is an array to work?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

I have been developing Java/JDBC calls to stored procedures with some success. However I am stuck when an output parameter is an array of strings. I have been successful with scalar types as input and output parameters, as well as an array of strings as an input parameter.

Here's the PL/SQL code I have:

```
TYPE StringArray IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

create or replace package body 
test is
  procedure upper(
    in_array     in StringArray,
    out_array    out StringArray
  ) is
    tmp StringArray := in_array;
  begin
    for i in 0..(tmp.count-1) loop
      tmp(i) := UPPER(tmp(i));
    end loop;
    out_array := tmp;
  end;
end test;
```

Here's the Java code I have:

```
public void testString(Connection connection) {
    String[] values = { "alpha", "beta", "gamma" };
    try {
       CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("begin test.upper(?, ?); end;");
       DelegatingConnection<OracleConnection> delegatingConnection = (DelegatingConnection<OracleConnection>) new DelegatingConnection(connection);
       OracleConnection oracleConnection = (OracleConnection) delegatingConnection.getInnermostDelegate();
       Array input oracleConnection.createOracleArray("STRINGARRAY", values);
       callableStatement.setObject("in_array", input);
       callableStatement.registerOutParameter("out_array", Types.ARRAY, "STRINGARRAY");
       callableStatement.execute();
       Array output = (Array)callableStatement.getObject("out_array");
       String[] result = (String[])output.getArray();
       System.out.println("Length: " + result.length);  // Prints "Length: 3"
       System.out.println("First: " + result[0]);       // Prints "First: null"
    } (catch SQLException e) {
       // Handle error
    }
}
```

If I call the PL/SQL stored procedure from an SQL script directly it works. So I think the stored procedure itself is okay.

If I call the stored procedure via JDBC it completes normally. Using debug statements, I have confirmed that `values` is correctly sent from the Java client to the stored procedure into `in_array`. That is, an array of length 3 with the appropriate values is received. As best as I can tell, `out_array` is sent back to the Java client. However, something goes wrong. `result` is of size 3 but all the elements are `null`.

If I inspect `output`, I can see that internally it has a `byte[]` of length 38. Sub-sequences of these bytes map to "ALPHA", "BETA" and "GAMMA". So it looks like the data makes it back to the client but it is not converted into a `String[]` correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the actual issue you facing. In PLSQL block or in JAVA call. Its not clear from your question

Comment: @XING As best I can tell, the PL/SQL is okay as the stored procedure completes normally. However, in the Java client code, the result is an array of the correct length but with `null` elements. So the data is not being transformed correctly at the client end. Based on this I think the issue is at the Java end, but you never know.

Comment: Maybe use vararrays or nested tables instead of associative arrays (index-by-tables). They wrote in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraarr.htm#JJDBC28574) that their JDBC driver supports varrarrays and nested tables, index-by-tables are nowhere mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: What makes the arrays associative? Is it the binary indexing?

Comment: Yes. `table of x index by y` is a PL/SQL associative array type. I don't know Java but the SQL-compatible collection types may give you more options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use an Associative Array - use a Collection:

```
CREATE TYPE StringArray IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
CREATE TYPE CLOBArray   IS TABLE OF CLOB;
```

Then you can do:

```
public void testString(Connection connection) {
  String[] values = { "alpha", "beta", "gamma" };
  try {
    OracleConnection oc = (OracleConnection) connection;

    ARRAY stringArray = oc.createARRAY( "STRINGARRAY", values ); // Upper case identifier

    OracleCallableStatement st = (OracleCallableStatement) oc.prepareCall(
      "begin test.upper( :in_array, :out_array ); end;"
    );

    st.setARRAYAtName( "in_array", stringArray );
    st.registerOutParameter( "out_array", Types.ARRAY, "STRINGARRAY"); // Upper case again
    st.execute();

    String[] result = (String[])st.getARRAY( 2 ).getArray();

    System.out.println("Length: " + result.length);
    System.out.println("First: " + result[0]);
  } (catch SQLException e) {
    // Handle error
  }
}
```

If you must use a PL/SQL associative array as an input to your procedure then write a function that takes a collection and outputs an associative array of the appropriate type and then call that:

```
BEGIN TEST.UPPER( TO_ASSOC_ARRAY( :in_collection ), :out_array ); END;
```

*Note: This answer is assuming using the Oracle driver in [ojdbc6.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html) which does not appear to have the [`OracleConnection.createOracleArray()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#createOracleArray_java_lang_String__java_lang_Object_) but it will, hopefully, be portable changing `oracle.sql.ARRAY` to `java.sql.Array` and using the newer methods.*

Comment: I'm pretty sure we're using `ojdbc7.jar`. Will that matter? Would you change your answer?

Comment: The key tip - do not use associative arrays - helped me solve my issue. By simply changing the type of `out_array`, I was able to receive an array of strings back from the stored procedure. I did not need to change any Java client code.