# Oracle SQL: create a dumy table from a substitution variable

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL, I can create a dummy table thanks to the code shown below:

```
select crca.*
from my_real_table real_table, 
     table(ntde.ENCRYPT_ALL(:inputParam)) enc
where
    ...
```

I would like to be able to do same thing without using `ntde.ENCRYPT_ALL`, I would like to do something like that:

```
select crca.*
from my_real_table real_table, 
     table(:inputParam) enc
where
    ...
```

It does not work and I get this error:

> 22905. 00000 -  "cannot access rows from a non-nested table item"
>        *Cause:    attempt to access rows of an item whose type is not known at
>        parse time or that is not of a nested table type
>        *Action:   use CAST to cast the item to a nested table type

Do you know how to do that please?

Comment: You have tagged [oracle-sqldeveloper], if this is what you are using then you probably need to [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with a complete example of how you are generating the bind variable and what value the bind variable has because I do not believe that SQL developer supports storing collection data types in bind variables. The list of data types it does support is given in the [`VARIABLE` documentation of the sql/plus user guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm).

Comment: Also, `:name` is a bind variable. `&name` is a substitution variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception says, use `CAST`:

```sql
SELECT c.*
FROM   my_real_table r 
       CROSS JOIN TABLE( CAST(:inputParam AS your_collection_type) ) c
```

This assumes that:

- the bind variable contains an collection (and not a string); and
- the bind variable is being passed from an application (this is a  [Java example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47711778/1509264)); and
- you have created an SQL collection type to cast the bind variable to. For example:

  ```sql
  CREATE TYPE your_collection_type AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  ```

  Or, instead of creating your own collection type, you could use a built in collection (or `VARRAY`) such as `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST`.