# Oracle19c : select query is failing with where clause (more than 19720 logical condition )

Tags: oracle, ojdbc, dbeaver, oracle19c

I am using following environment :

1. Oracle 19.0.0.0
2. Windows 10
3. ojdbc8.jar

Using Oracle19c as database with DBeaver`https://dbeaver.io/` SQL client (which internally uses odjbc8.jar driver ) where i am executing below SQL query

```
select * from Student
  WHERE RollNo=1 OR RollNo=2 OR RollNo=3 OR RollNo=4 OR .... OR RollNo=19720
```

Above query is failed with below exception:

```
SQL Error [17410] [08000]: No more data to read from socket
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForReading(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:119)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:534)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:485)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:213)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:37)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:733)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:904)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1082)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1737)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1692)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:300)
```

Can you please help me here ?

1. There is some limitation introduced on Logical operator in oracle19c ?
2. Or i have to do some settings (database level settings) to do work this query (I know changing the query to IN clause solve my problem).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just pass a Java array to an Oracle collection and then check if the value is contained in the array (rather than dynamically generating statements with tens-of-thonuands of `OR` conditions). Some examples: [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37161584/1509264)] [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699771/1509264)] [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47711778/1509264)]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can either use a BETWEEN clause:

```
select * from Student
  WHERE RollNo BETWEEN 1 AND 19720
```

or use the equivalent `>=` / `<=` pair:

```
select * from Student
  WHERE RollNo >= 1 AND
        RollNo <= 19720
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. There is some limitation introduced on Logical operator in oracle19c ?**

No, but ["Logical Database Limits"](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76.htm#REFRN0043) states:

> **Note:**
>
> The limit on how long a SQL statement can be depends on many factors, including database configuration, disk space, and memory

**2. Or i have to do some settings (database level settings) to do work this query (I know changing the query to IN clause solve my problem).**

Even if some changes(like increasing memory, etc) can allow to increase a number of your `OR`s, it still will not be reliable solution. So it's much better to use collections (or global temporary tables in case of problems with JPPD (join predication push-down)).

Btw, simple `IN` condition (`x in (1,2,3...1000)`) has a limitation in 1000 expressions
(ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000), but you can use tuples `(0,x) in ((0,1),(0,2),(0,3)...(0,1000),...(0,10000))`

Comment: @ Sayan Malakshinov : If i divide the query into multiple IN Clause e.g. select * from Student WHERE RollNo IN (1....1000) OR RollNo IN (1001....2000) OR RollNo IN (20001....21000) OR RollNo IN (21001....21000) it is failing with SQL Error [17410] [08000]: No more data to read from socket whereas if i reduce one IN clause it is working properly. I am suspecting some timeout issue or query length. Can you please help me here?